# How to send this URL to the view from django in a form submit way?

Tags: django

I have a URL like this under `new_password.html` in Django:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/new_password/zBfPGsMBWbAPVXeH6FMMrpDAODd4Cbukc6ca0ddb55be603a46c977f6d08feb9e763ef583c9f1f9d7d0ba88bb32b6368bebc9c96075185beb/hello.technerves@gmail.com
```

When the user presses the button Submit in the form I want this URL to go to `update` view in Django. Is it possible?

```
url(r'^new_password', 'fileupload.views.new_password'),
url(r'^update_password', 'fileupload.views.update_password'),

def new_password(request):
    return render_to_response('new_password.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def update_password(request): 
    ...This is where I want to get the URL parameter.
```

Comment: Are you needing to access a specific parameter of the request? or...?

Comment: I am going to need the email address i.e hello.technerves@gmail.com

Comment: Would need to see your urls.py and views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to simply split the path and retrieve the last item in the list. If you're submitting the value in a POST, say with a hidden field called "url", you could do:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('url').split('/')[-1]
        ...
```

That assumes that the entire value of the url in your original question is the value of the "url" form field.

Comment: With request.path I am getting the current URL not the URL I want.

Comment: Ok. One way to get the URL is to add it to a hidden form field and post it to your view. How is the value for the URL being sent to the initial view?

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer showing how to retrieve the value from a POST.

Comment: I know how to do this. But I don't have url value in the new_password view to send to the update_password view.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know quite what you're asking then.

Comment: I used javascript to get the URL and pass to the view as a hidden value. Thanks mate.